# APNs on Lion. What's possible?

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications

I am planning out a Mac OS X (Lion) application and wanted to ask some questions about APNs.

First off: Can you send APNs to a Lion Application that is something other than a Badge or Alert? That is, can you perhaps send a key/value pair or some such data to the end-point application that it can use to determine what action to take? Pretty sure I could do this in iOS land but not for Mac OS X

Will the application that receives the event be able to do so - even if it's in the background?

Lastly, does the application need to have a UI? i.e. can I write a back-ground only application that can be the end-point for the notification?

What I really am trying to work out is if I can leverage APNs on Lion as general purpose mechanism for alerting my application to do something or if it's purely for delivering UI alerts?

Answer (score 0):

You can only register for badge alerts (NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) but you can send the same payload type as in iOS and the Mac app will receive it. So far I've only managed to get running and background apps to receive the notification, but the [docs say:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

> Mac OS X Note: Because the only notification type supported for
>   non-running applications is icon-badging

So it seems like non-running apps should be able to get the notification, but I haven't figured that out yet.

Here's my app receiving a notification in the background:

```
2012-02-13 18:00:39.531 TestPush[25580:707] Received Push Alert: TESTING
2012-02-13 18:00:39.532 TestPush[25580:707] Received Push Badge: 10
2012-02-13 18:00:44.153 TestPush[25580:707] applicationDidResignActive
2012-02-13 18:00:57.233 TestPush[25580:707] remote notification: {
    "_" = "n7dBZFYpEeGiNBT+tdMfCA";
    aps =     {
        alert = TESTING;
        badge = 10;
    };
}
```

Here's a custom payload (key/value pairs that you mentioned):

```
2012-02-13 18:23:44.665 TestPush[25958:707] remote notification: {
    "_" = "zsUPTFYsEeGiNBT+tdMfCA";
    acme1 = bar;
    acme2 = 42;
    aps =     {
        alert = "You got your emails.";
        badge = 9;
        sound = "bingbong.aiff";
    };
}
2012-02-13 18:23:44.666 TestPush[25958:707] Received Push Alert: You got your emails.
2012-02-13 18:23:44.666 TestPush[25958:707] Received Push Sound: bingbong.aiff
2012-02-13 18:23:44.667 TestPush[25958:707] Received Push Badge: 9
2012-02-13 18:23:44.667 TestPush[25958:707] Received cust1: bar
2012-02-13 18:23:44.668 TestPush[25958:707] Received cust2: 42
```

Not sure about the UI part, I wouldn't have thought you need a UI though.

Also check out this sample code from Apple [PushyMac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PushyMac/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011126-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).